# Create a Moq Mock from System.Type

Tags: .net, reflection, moq

Is it possible to create a Mock from a System.Type variable?

We are converting projects from Rhino to Moq.
In Rhino we could previously do this:

```
var type = typeof(/* Some type */);
MockRepository.GenerateStub(type);
```

The creation methods in Moq are (at least as far as I have found) all based on generic type parameters instead of System.Type.

Unfortunately there are a lot of different types for which a Mock is needed packed in different infrastructure layers and handed over as a variable of System.Type to the point where the Mock is created. So converting all this to generic is very cumbersome if it can be done at all.

Comment: RhinoMocks uses generics too because it's *easier*. The [landing page itself](https://hibernatingrhinos.com/oss/rhino-mocks) shows `MockRepository.GenerateStub<IUserRepository>();`. It was your project's choice to not use the easy option for whatever reason. The entire phrase `Unfortunately there are a lot of different types for which a Mock is needed packed in different infrastructure layers and handed over as a variable of System.Type to the point where the Mock is created` suggests some serious design problems - Mocks are created on the *outside*.

Comment: What does your code and project do? It's clearly *not* using RhinoMock the way it's intended. You need to explain that so people can come up with an alternative. Moq was created from the start to work in a LINQ-like way which means Expressions and Generics.

Comment: Worst case, you may have to use Reflection to generate the generic Mock with `var myMockType=typeof(Mock<>).MakeGenericType(new[]{YourType});`. and then `object o = Activator.CreateInstance(constructed);`. Setting up that mock won't be easy, even if you use `dynamic` instead of `object`. You may have to keep using reflection to create the Expression calls used by Moq to configure itself

Comment: Perhaps you can bypass the problem by using [Moq.AutoMocker](https://github.com/moq/Moq.AutoMocker), essentially an IoC for mocks. You can use `var car = mocker.CreateInstance<Car>();` or `var car = mocker.CreateInstance(typeof(Car),false);` to create a mocked Car instance. You can get access to the object's mocks and verify assertions after that

Comment: I ended up doing it the reflection way of @PanagiotisKanavos but AutoMocker looks good for other purposes. I did not know that existed. Thanks again.